# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf, enums

When working with WCF many times the exception massage doesn’t help us to solve the 
problem. The above massage is usually a symptom for one of the following problems:

1. The return values are bigger than the value which was defined in the config file.
2. There is a problem with the endpoint setting
3. There is a problem with serialization of the data

I experienced the 3rd problem which was with enums
The problem was that the an enum was defined explicitly with values

```
  Public Enum FrequencyEnums
        EveryTime = 1
        OncePerHour = 2
        OncePerDay = 3
        OncePerWeek = 4
        Never = 5
    End Enum
```

And the private property that was using this enum was defined as follows

```
Private m_sendFrequencyID As FrequencyEnums
```

Now because the enum does not have a definition of a default value and 
because the property is not initialized explicitly and 
because the enum value for 0 is missing from the enum and
because the default value of enum regardless of the specified options is always 0
When I tried to return instance of this class to the client I got this error:
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

The solution is one of the following:

1. Define 0 value for enums or
2. Define a default value for a property from the enum values.
3. Assign initial  value to the property

My question is how could I have found this error with Microsoft tools and not by trial and error?

Answer (score 2):

Found this a while ago trying to resolve the same error message (I had a different issue). Enabling trace and use `svctraceviewer.exe` to look at the trace log helped me a lot. Please see the following URL for more information:
[Enable WCF Trace Log](http://mint.litemedia.se/2010/01/20/wcf-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a data contract for the enum. See: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/merrickchaffer/archive/2007/04/03/Passing-Enum-values-into-WCF-Service-operations.aspx

Comment: The question is how to determine the problem, not how to solve it. The difficulties are to find out it from this exception: "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly", which doesn't say much.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems with WCF, often the error is very general or misleading. Which means that you cannot go from the error message to what the problem is. You need to look at what you are doing as much as what the error message is.

Comment: WCF specifically and by design uses "error masking", e.g. it by design doesn't reveal too much information about the error. Let's face it - most of the time, that info doesn't really help the end user anyway.....